# O que está de errado no meu código?

Tags: javascript

```
var quantidade = "200";

setInterval(function(){
    var tempo     = document.getElementById("banner").textContent; 
    var match     = tempo.match(/[^\d](\d+)/);
    var nr        = match && match[1];
    if(nr === "5"){
        var red   = document.getElementById("red").textContent;
        var green = document.getElementById("green").textContent;
        var black = document.getElementById("black").textContent;
        if(red>black){
            var corfinal = "black";
            $("#enviarpreto").click();
        }else{
          var corfinal = "red";
          $("#enviarvermelho").click();
        }
    }

   if(tempo[5] === "d"){
       var red2     = document.getElementById("red").textContent;
       var green2   = document.getElementById("green").textContent;
       var black2   = document.getElementById("black").textContent;
       var meured   = document.getElementById("meured").textContent;
       var meublack = document.getElementById("meublack").textContent;
       if(meured < 0){
           quantidade = quantidade*2;
       }else if(meupreto < 0){
           quantidade = quantidade*2
       }else{
           quantidade = 200;
       }
       document.getElementById('betAmount').value = quantidade;
   }
}, 1000);
```

O que pretendo fazer é que quando a condição tempo[5] === d acontecer, que multiplique, caso aqueles valores sejam negativos. Porém, só quero que multiplique uma vez. Mas deparamo-me com um problema como está em setinterval, está constantemente a multiplicar, pois o tempo[5], fica durante 4 segundos.

Como poderei para que aquilo apenas me faça 1x?

Obrigado.

Comment: Uma dica, indentar o código ajuda a encontrar quaisquer erros nele. Não necessariamente lhe fará encontrar o erro, mas reduzirá o esforço necessário para chegar lá.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Renan!

Answer (score 4):

Você deve limpar o intervalo assim que sua condição for satisfeita.

**Dessa forma:**

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
                  // definir condição.
                  if(n == 5){
                    // limpe o interval para parar a execução.  
                    clearInterval(myVar);
                  }       
            }, 1000);
```

Então acredito, que basta definir o `clearInterval` dentro do seu `if(tempo[5] === "d")` para executar a rotina apenas uma vez.

Atualização :

Testei aqui funcionou sem dar erro no meu navegador, no entanto eu não
usaria um script assim. É loop infinito. Fiz porque me pediu. Portanto ao pessoal que vai fazer cara torta e pensar em downvotes. Saibam; **eu jamais usaria isso!**

```
CallTimeOut = function(){
       var myTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
       // execute aqui sua rotina 
       //Aqui embaixo sua condição para encerrar o TimeOut  if(tempo[5] === "d")
       if(1==1) clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
   },1000);
}

setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof(myTimeOut) == 'undefined'){
        CallTimeOut(); 
    }   
},1000);
```

Só um adicional:

lembrar que `setTimeout` vai executar sua rotina após X milissegundos, no caso acima 1000 ms que é igual a um segundo e não ira executar mais.

e `setInterval`, executa uma rotina a cada X milissegundos no caso ali também 1 segundo, portanto nem precisa daquele `clearTimeout` ele vai executar e parar e novamente será invocado por `setInterval`.

Comment: Isto está a funcionar da primeira vez, mas depois preciso de que o set interval volte a entrar. Ou seja preciso só que me faça 1x, depois espero pelo tempo em que aquilo fica ativo e que o setinterval volte a ficar. E esta condição está-me a acabar completamente com o setinterval

Comment: Me explique melhor, o que isso faz? Eu não compreendi seu comentário. Porque precisa ficar executando essa verificação de segundo em segundo?

Comment: Pq o tempo é um cronometro, e eu tenho outras condições dentro desse setinterval

Comment: Se existir alguma maneira, de apos o clear interval, voltar a ativar o setinterval era o ideial

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi bem, mas acho que você poderia usar setTimeout aonde colocou  setInterval,  e colocar dentro do scopo de uma função. Em seguida definir um setInterval no seu scopo global do script com uma condição de fim de execução do setTimeout invocando novamente a função. Isso daria a funcionalidade que pretende.

Comment: Poderia-me dar um exemplo?